# Get link inside several p elements using xpath

Tags: xpath

I have the following code (as part of a page):

```
<div class="examples">
<p class="update">Day 1 : <a href="example.php?s=997">exampletext</a></p>
<p class="update">Day 1 : <a href="example.php?s=998">exampletext</a></p>
<p class="update">Day 1 : <a href="example.php?s=999">exampletext</a></p>
<p class="update">Day 1 : <a href="example.php?s=1000">exampletext</a></p>
<p class="update">Day 1 : <a href="example.php?s=1001">exampletext</a></p>
<p class="update">Day 1 : <a href="example.php?s=1002">exampletext</a></p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the link (href and title) using xpath. There are several "update" p class elements on the same page, i need them all. I'm not really interested for the "Day 1 : " text (or whatever day gets there).

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible xpath :

```
//div[@class='examples']/p[@class='update']/a
```

Output :

```
'<a href="example.php?s=997">exampletext</a>'
'<a href="example.php?s=998">exampletext</a>'
'<a href="example.php?s=999">exampletext</a>'
'<a href="example.php?s=1000">exampletext</a>'
'<a href="example.php?s=1001">exampletext</a>'
'<a href="example.php?s=1002">exampletext</a>'
```